# EO pdf background image

Tags: css, pdf

We are using EO.pdf 16, we have css for body tag

```css
body {
 background-image: url(../images/background.jpg);
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
 background-position: center center;
    /*background-size: cover;*/
 height: 98%;
    width:100%;
 padding: 0px !important;
 margin: 0px !important; 
}
```

We want the background-image on the browser but not in the PDF.

Thanks in advance,
Anjan

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is fixed in version 16.2.9 of EO.